# Cassandra not restoring snapshot data properly

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using Cassandra 3.11.3 version in my 3 node cluster, I am planning to migrate to GCP. I have installed same version in GCP. I am taken snapshot and tried to restore but not all tables are loaded properly.
I am using many UDF's in my schema and also schema got changed many times in original cluster. I have created schema in new cluster using generated schema by existing cluster. not sure what todo. please guide me to solve the issue.

Comment: how do you restore data - show the command...

Comment: I have solved the issue using ss loader...

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest alternatives for that, so you may avoid streaming from snapshots:

- Add machines that you installed at GCP as [new datacenter to existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html), wait until migration finishes, decommission old data center. The advantage of this approach is that you will have zero downtime during migration - your applications could work with data in old data center, and then you can switch to new one (or run in parallel for a some time);
- Just copy complete content of the Cassandra's data directories to GCP, copy configs (only adjust IP addresses, etc.), and start Cassandra.